# Wordpress Frontend user field with HTML

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I was wondering if someone could please help me clean up how this displays on the fronted, I use this to display a directory of users that are entered in a ACF field on some posts. Each field will have multiple users. I would like to have a bullet point for each user followed by their info and then each email address to be a mailto link.

```
<?php
$users = get_field('pds_construction_coordinators', '');
echo "<ul>";
foreach($users as $user){
    $user_id = $user['ID'];
    $user_email = $user['user_email'];
    $user_display_name = $user['display_name'];
    $user_company = get_field('company_name', 'user_'.$user_id);
    $user_phone = get_field('phone_number', 'user_'.$user_id);


    echo "<li> $user_company, $user_display_name, <a href="mailto:<?php echo ($user_email); ?>"><?php echo $user_email; ?></a>, $user_phone </li>";

    echo "<br />";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? At the moment you're just using `echo` to print the various data. Have you tried using `<ul>` for the list, and then `<a>` for the link?

Comment: My issue is when I try to make the email a link, everything I try it errors, see my updated code with the bullets.

Comment: If you want the bullet to be 1 per user, the `<ul>` opening should be before your `foreach` and the closing `</ul>` should be after.

Comment: There's no other indication of the email link in your code. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/6273251) for info on how much research effort is expected of you when asking a question here

Comment: The code right now is working for the bullets, but I will move the <ul> around. I am not that familiar with using HTML with php, that’s why I am asking for help. I did research to get the bullets to work. Everything I keep trying for the email link keeps causing a error.

Comment: This is what I have been messing with <a href="mailto:<?php echo ($user_email); ?>"><?php echo $user_email; ?></a>

Comment: You _are_ in a `<?php ... ?>` section there already, so you can not use `<?php ...` _again_ at this point. Use string concatenation, or https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is what ended up working for me, not the cleanest, but it works:

```
<?php
$users = get_field('pds_construction_coordinators', '');
echo "<ul>";
foreach($users as $user){

$user_id = $user['ID'];
$user_email = $user['user_email'];
$user_display_name = $user['display_name'];
$user_company = get_field('company_name', 'user_'.$user_id);
$user_phone = get_field('phone_number', 'user_'.$user_id);

echo "<li>";
echo "<strong>$user_company</strong> <br/>";
echo "$user_display_name <br/>";
echo "$user_phone <br/>";
echo "<a href='mailto:$user_email'>$user_email</a><br/>";
echo "</li>";
}
echo "<ul>";
```